# why producer thread producing more one item even iam setting capacity to 1 also

Tags: java, concurrency

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class ProducerAndConsummerUsingBlockingqueue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Producerqueue(blockingQueue));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Consumner(blockingQueue));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

}

class Producerqueue implements Runnable {

    BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue;

    public Producerqueue(BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue) {
        this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("produced item " + i);
                blockingQueue.put(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}

class Consumner implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue;

    public Consumner(BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue) {
        this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("consumed item " + blockingQueue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Even i was set capacity 1 for producer then also the output like below.I am not understanding producing item is more than 1 even i am setting capacity to 1

```
produced item 1
produced item 2
consumed item 1
produced item 3
consumed item 2
produced item 4
consumed item 3
produced item 5
consumed item 4
produced item 6
consumed item 5
produced item 7
consumed item 6
produced item 8
consumed item 7
produced item 9
consumed item 8
produced item 10
consumed item 9
consumed item 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Capacity means how many items the queue can hold at one time. Also, the way you've set up your `Producerqueue` it will print the message before trying to put new items into the queue. That means that your will see a message like *produced item 2*  but the `blockingQueue.put(i);` statement will block until it can add a new item to the queue without surpassing its capacity.

For short, your producer prints its message before it adds new items to the queue.